# Get integer from a URL in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-javascript-sdk, javascript-objects

I have a URL like this-

> http‍://localhost/gtwhero/public/users/13/subscribers-lists/30/subscribers

So it's format is like this-

> http‍://localhost/gtwhero/public/users/{**user_id**}/subscribers-lists/{**list_id**}/subscribers

I want to get the **user_id** and **list_id** from the URL.

So what I have done is

```
var a = parseInt("http://localhost/gtwhero/public/users/13/subscribers-lists/30/subscribers");
```

But as a result I am getting -

```
NaN
```

So, I think there must be another way of getting those two integers.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parseInt` wont work in this case, it'll always return `NaN` as your string contains alphabets.

You need to use regex to extract the user id from URL

```js
var url = 'http://localhost/gtwhero/public/users/13/subscribers-lists/30/subscribers';
var data = (url.match(/(\d+)/g) || []);

var userId = data[0],
  listId = data[1];

document.write("userId " + userId);
document.write("<br />listId " + listId);
```

Note: this will only work specifically for the above shown URLs, if URL contains other digits, it need to be used properly to extract intended ids.